# Hammer Editor - "Unexpected End of File" On Load, Reading Chunks 33%

Tags: hammer

First of all, I know questions similar to this have been answered, but yet I cannot find the solution.

I was saving my map after doing some stuff with logic entities. Upon saving, Hammer quit without any message. Upon attempted loading, Hammer comes up with "*File C:...mapname.vmf, line 18838: unexpected end of file*", with another window saying *"Loading Chunks..."* Then 33%. I have read that editing the .vmf file to add a curly bracket } at the end to close the whatever it's called. I found mine was missing one, so I added it, now when ever I open the same map it loads to 33% again, then crashes, all in under a second.

So, simply: Any solutions? Also, I am using the Hammer Editor with HL2 in the base.

It's kind of sad I have to write this one about 2 hours after my other H.E question.

Answer (score 1):

Your map file is corrupted.

You can either put a closing `}` into line 18838 (the one the game complains about) or if that doesn't work you can replace it as follows:

- rename your <mapname>.vmf to something else (or make a backup)
- locate the <mapname>.**vmx** in your mapsrc folder and copy it over
- rename the vmx extension to vmf
- try to load the newly renamed <mapname>.vmf in Hammer

If that still doesn't work your last resort lies inside your <HammerFolder>/autosaves. If you have some autosave files you can try one of these to recover your map. They might not be the latest version, but still better than nothing.

Comment: When I add a single curly bracket to line 18838 (the bottom one, which is missing a curly), and then run the map, it just "_Loads Chunks_" to 33%, then closes. However, using two curly brackets brings the same "_unexpected end of file_" issue as before. I cannot exactly tell how many I need (If I may need more), or there is still somehow corruption.

For your second tip, I also tried that, it brings the same result as a single curly: "_Loading Chunks_" 33%.

Comment: Do you happen to have some hammerAutosave files? One of these could still save you.

Comment: I do, but it is from about 2-3 days ago. I have a more recent version on an external source, however it is missing a great deal of work compared to how I had it. If need be, I will put the time and effort into it again.

Comment: +1 for having backups. Too bad the autosaves are too old, though.

Comment: Is there a way to change the frequency of the auto-backup to make it occur more often?

Comment: Yes. [right here](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Hammer_General_Options)